# Function with parameters does not run inside Javascript AddEventListener

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, addeventlistener

In NuxtJS I am trying to run a function with two parameters when an element is clicked with an `AddEventListener`.

```
async handleSubmit(recipe, userRating) {some code...}

setup(recipe) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.recipe-rating > .star').forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function(el) {
        const userRating = el.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-rating');
        this.handleSubmit(recipe, userRating);
    }, false);
  });
...more code...
}
```

All of the code is within `methods: {}`, and I get the following error when clicking.

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.handleSubmit is not a function at SVGSVGElement.eval
```

How can I fix the problem, and what is the problem with my code?

Comment: And what is `SVGSVGElement.eval`?

Comment: use an arrow function, or bind that function to `this` or use the old `_this = this` trick - by the way, if you're using addEventListener with vuejs, you're probably doing something wrong

Comment: or just put the code of handle submit in the event listener.

Comment: @TheFool - as long as "some code" doesn't make the same wrong assumption about what `this` is

Comment: Thank you all for the input. In the end I "fixed" it by just using VueJS `v-on:click` with a `v-for` in the HTML istead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On way around this problem is to use `Vue.js` with the `HTML` element instead of trough a `.js` file. With `v-on:click` ([se Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html)) we can run a function when the user clicks the `HTML` element.

```
<svg v-for="(el, i) in 5" :key="i" :data-rating="el" @click="handleSubmit(recipe, el)">
  <polygon />
</svg>
```

Note: `v-on:click` changes to `@click` with `ESLint`.